# How to move the insertion point at begin of a NSTextView?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

In iOS I used to use:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainTextField: UITextView!

let newPosition = mainTextField.beginningOfDocument
mainTextField.selectedTextRange = mainTextField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
```

But NSTextView has no member 'beginningOfDocument'. How can I get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moveToBeginningOfDocument(_:)` is what you're looking for.

Searching the documentation for 'beginningOfDocument' should find it but it doesn't.